# Good Emulators/Simulators (Android, iOS)

Tags: php, android, ios, seetest

I'm looking for some good testing tools (emulators) for Android and iOS to test my PHP web app on. 
I short-listed the following

1) Robotium for Android 
2) Seetest - http://experitest.com/support/download-2/

Can anyone of you post your views on this? Can you please suggest any good ones apart from these.

Regards,
Abhijit.

Comment: are you looking for open source?

Comment: are you looking for testing framework for android, iphone or only emulators? Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.qatestingtools.com/android-guitar

http://seleniumhq.org/ - This is open source and its latest version will support for Android and IPhone.